# What is the standard naming convention of properties in a object, camelCase or snake_case?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

What is the standard convention naming for property inside object?

> camelCase

or

> snake_case?

Here's an example:

```
let objPerson = {
    first_name: 'first',
    last_name: 'last'
};
```

or

```
let objPerson = {
    firstName: 'first',
    lastName: 'last'
};
```

Any recommendation for a site to learn naming standardization of objects? I tried to google it but couldn't find an answer. Also the name of the object should be `objPerson` or `ObjPerson` because it is an object

Comment: You can choose - only real convention for name format is to start constructor and classes with a capital (and even then it's your own choice).

Comment: i would go for the second option, because it is shorter to write and underscores makes code nervous.

Comment: PascalCase for classes and camelCase for the rest are conventional in JS. There's no official standard.

Comment: There is no rule, however there is a rule that string literals should be terminated.

Comment: As other have said, it's a matter of personal preference (I'm on board with @estus). Whatever you decide on, it might be a good idea to set up eslint and set a rule with your choice, so you are consistent.

Comment: oh thanks.. i think js has rules for it, i think i will go into snake case..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not really a standard, but i've seen more snake case in my days. You can choose whatever you like, it's just important that you use the same type during a project.